# Not getting a callback with Ajax.BeginForm asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am unable to hit the server code using Ajax.BeginForm()

Here is part of my View where I used the Ajax Helper method

@model Ride.MMReports.ViewModels.ManualRecViewModel

.....

```
var options = new AjaxOptions
{
    OnBegin = "OnBeginMethod",
    OnFailure = "OnFailureMethod",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccessMethod",
    OnComplete = "OnCompleteMethod",
    HttpMethod = "Post"
};

using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ManRecReport", options))
{
    <button type="submit"
    name="action"
    value="Export to excel"
    id="export-excel"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    Export to excel
    </button>
}

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/report")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

My bundle include jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and also reports.js where I have all the event methods

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

reports.js bellow. The browser is able to show the alert but last method it calls is OnFailureMethod

```
var isError = false;

function OnBeginMethod() {
    alert("OnBeginMethod");
}

function OnFailureMethod(error) {
    isError = true;
    alert("OnFailure");
}

function OnSuccessMethod(data) {
    alert("OnSuccess");
}

function OnCompleteMethod(data, status) {
    if (!isError) {
        alert("OnCompleteMethod");
    }
}
```

The problem here is when I click the button, jquery-3.1.1.js is failing 
**http://localhost:31111/[object%20HTMLButtonElement] 404 (Not Found)**
 failing at this line

```
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

My Controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(ManualRecViewModel vm)
{
  ....
}
```

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how your controller action looks like?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I put the controllers code also

Comment: Please change `using(Ajax.BeginForm..` to `@using(Ajax.BeginForm..` . In Razor every content using a @ block is automatically HTML encoded by Razor.

Comment: that block is inside and @if(....) so the razor is valid, I just put the snippet of code to illustrate the scenario